# What does "whom you are." mean in this sentence? "Remember who you are and whom you are."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The following sentence is from a letter written to a mother who has cancer in order to give her hope, courage and strength.

> **"Remember who you are and whom you are."** [Link](https://familyreach.org/blog/letters-from-moms-with-cancer-advice-for-when-youre-mom-and-patient/)

I can understand "Remember who you are" because it is grammatical and very easy to understand, but I can't quite understand what **"Remember whom you are**" means?

What do you think it means?

Comment: I can't even guess. I imagine the writer had some profound meaning in mind, but it escapes me.

Comment: I'm with Jeffrey Carney. Btw, there's a note on the use of 'whom' [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/who), but you may not need it.